# IMAP IDLE many accounts in PHP

Tags: php, imap

I can't seem to find out a way to monitor a large number of IMAP accounts for changes. When something changes in any of those accounts I want to push their account_id in a queue so a free worker can connect and fetch the changes (and eventually update other services with the fetched information).

I am using PHP to connect and fetch the messages in each account, my PHP library supports IMAP IDLE but is it true that with PHP I would only be able to monitor 1 account with 1 process? So I would need hundreds to thousands of processes to monitor all accounts (which would require way to many resources).

Currently about 100 accounts, but can grow to 3 - 4k eventually.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how flexible the IMAP library is. Basically, it needs two things: to expose the TCP connection it uses (resource; file handle; file descriptor...), and to have two separate functions to "send IDLE" and "wait for replies" (rather than just an opaque "send IDLE and block" function).

At the lowest level, when you have multiple connections, you can wait for activity on all of them at once, using functions like `select()`, `poll()`, *epoll*, or *kqueue*. Using one of these methods, you can make a simple event loop:

1. Ask the IMAP library to send `IDLE` commands to all IMAP connections.
2. Give all TCP connections to `select()` and wait for it to return.
3. Eventually `select()` will return a list of TCP connections that have some activity (received data or lost connection).
4. For each TCP connection, look up the corresponding IMAP connection, and ask the IMAP library to read all responses from it.
5. Handle the responses.
6. Repeat.

Unfortunately PHP only offers select() though – [stream_select()](http://php.net/stream_select) for "streams" and [socket_select()](http://php.net/socket_select) for "sockets". That should be enough for a few dozen connections, but quite frankly I wouldn't expect it – or PHP at all – to work well with hundreds or thousands. In fact, I vaguely remember most operating systems having a limit of 64 or so fd's in `select()`, but I'll have to update this later...

Comment: What language you suggest for just this "notification" part? As when I just have an 'account_id' and am able to put this into a queue like beanstalkd I could use PHP to do the heavy lifting (fetching, parsing etc).

Comment: @Floris: I'm not sure generally, but for more than a hundred connections, I'd go with a language that allows using Linux "epoll" or BSD "kqueue" (and has a good IMAP library too of course)... From the higher-level ones, Ruby or Python or JS (via Node.js) might work.

Comment: I only found inboxapp doing something similar, but they aren't really built for scale it seems. Any alternatives?